# I want to know the file_path in the example of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, filepath, input-parameters

The example of tensorflow is
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio

I want to know the `file_path` in this example as below:

```
def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform, label
```

The 'file_path' is called in the function as below:

```
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

I tried to get the value of the file_path using the `print(file_path)`, but the answer is `Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`.

That is not the exact value of file_path.

Finally, I don't know the value of the `file_path` and input parameters of `get_waveform_and_label` in the `waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)`.

Answer (score -1):

I have been stuck in the same problem, but I think I got it:

The **file_path** comes from the **file_ds** variable, where **file_ds** "[represents potentially a large set of element](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)", where each element is the 'file path' to each of the wav. file.

After you set the *train_files* variable, run the following to see what I mean.

```
file_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
for element in dataset:
  print(element)
```

Then when you use the map function

```
file_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label)
```

It's applyting the function `get_waveform_and_label` to each of the elements of the large set, in this case to each wav file.

references: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Comment: Thank you for your answering but I still wonder how to print `file_path` in `def get_waveform_and_label(file_path)`.